# Awesome Cropper canvas is empty on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, crop

I'm using **[Awesome Cropper](https://github.com/Andrew8xx8/awesome-cropper)** plugin and everything works fine but there is a little issue there, if you open an image til you don't click on selected area or move it, it won't generate any image as output, i want when a user open an image then press apply button without any click or move on selected area, it going to crop image where area selection stand by default. I tried to find any solution in js files but no success. so there is a trick, if you click selected area it going to do this but i can't simulate click or mouseDown/Up, i tried these codes but didn't works. any solution?

```
  setInterval(function(){ 
  $('.imgareaselect-border4').click();
  console.log('clicked');
  }, 1000);
```

**or**

```
  setInterval(function(){ 
  $('.imgareaselect-border4').mouseup();
  console.log('clicked');
  }, 1000);
```

**or**

```
  setInterval(function(){ 
  $('.imgareaselect-border4').mousedown();
  console.log('clicked');
  }, 1000);
```

**[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/p5oc5vwr/)**

*(note: when you selected an image please don't move cropper or click first, you see? just click apply button, yes.. it didn't generate any image, then run again this fiddle, now just click on selected area, it will generate image. exactly i want this)*

you can see awesome cropper js [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Client-Side-Image-Cropping-Plugin-Awesome-Cropper/build/jquery.awesome-cropper.js) and image real select [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Client-Side-Image-Cropping-Plugin-Awesome-Cropper/components/imgareaselect/scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.js).